# Why Three.js 90 degrees doesn't looks like it rotates 90 degrees

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I have a three.js cylinder that I need to rotate 90 degrees from its center.

When the cylinder is not rotate it looks like this:

[image: cylinder not rotated]

The code for the cylinder when its not rotated is this:

```
const mainCylinderMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: new THREE.Color("#888"),
  reflectivity: 0.5,
  shininess: 100,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
const mainCylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.075, 0.075, 0.76, 50, 50);
const mainCylinderMesh = new THREE.Mesh(mainCylinderGeometry, mainCylinderMaterial);
```

But as soon as I try to rotate it it looks like this:

[image: cylinder rotated 90 degrees]

So I only add one line of code which is this one:

```
mainCylinderMesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 90);
```

I also tried this:

```
mainCylinderMesh.rotation.z = 90;
```

I don't know why it does this if you can help please. (sorry if it's dumb)

Comment: Use radians, not degrees: `Math.PI / 2`.

Comment: Three.js provides conversion utilities, too. Degrees to radians: [`MathUtils.degToRad`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/MathUtils.degToRad) Radians to degrees: [`MathUtils.radToDeg`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/MathUtils.radToDeg)

Comment: Oh, thanks for that info on the utilities, but I think writing ```Math.PI / 2``` will be easier and less confusing